# Excel sheets with VB code running gives error while opening new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with button start and stop. If I click button start, it starts getting values from sheet named Prices until I click stop button. It works perfectly. 
But when I open a new empty excel sheet it gives an error "subscript out of range". My problem is first excel should work at background if I press start button and I should be able to open any number of other workbooks.

I have given below part of my code where error comes.

```
Sub StartDataUpdate()
    TimerActive = True
    UpdateData
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateData()
    If TimerActive Then

        ConnectDB

        Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim LocalTime As String
        LocalTime = Format(Now(), "YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS")

        With Sheets("Price")
            For rowCursor = 2 To 10
                 //Code to insert data in database
            Next

        End With

        Set rs1.ActiveConnection = Nothing
        oConn.Close
        RepeatUpdate
    End If
End Sub
```

Error comes at the line `With Sheets("Price")` as **subscript out of range** when I open a new empty excel sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sheets("Price")` is not always set to the workbook of the macro. Try `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Price")` In that case, it will only look at the workbook where the macro is in.

Comment: Actually it doesn't give any error. But the new excel hangs. Unable to click on the cell as it gives loading symbol. What I am doing is on clicking start button I retrieves value from cell and inserts on mysql database. This happens every second until I click stop button. Kindly help.

Comment: Is your code running in a constant loop? Then you could think about using Application.Wait: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.wait This pauses the script for a chosen amount of time. That gives you the opportunity to do stuff in between updates.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But if I uses wait method, it stops the macro running at background I guess. It should not stop because prices like commodities or currency changes every second and it has to be updated. What I need is I should be able to work on new excel sheets without any hindrance besides running macro at background.

Comment: Then I think the only solution would be that you open an extra instance of Excel and open new workbooks in there.